# C# string.Replace for removing �?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I am converting hex to a UTF8 string using below line.

`var obInstruction = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ob.Bits);`

In the result I got � between every character as shown in the picture below.
what is � ?

[image: what is �]

So I added replace to the line and changed it to
`var obInstruction = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ob.Bits).Replace("�", "");` but � won't go away.

When I tried to replace other characters `Replace` work fine but not for �.

What is � and how can I remove it?

In Power query, `Text.Clean` will remove such strange characters but I am not sure how to do in C#.

*Edit: added a picture for the result with UTF32
Empty boxes with UTF32:

[image: empty boxes with UTF32]

Comment: Is your original string in UTF32 encoding?

Comment: @TimurUmerov I think it is UTF8 because with UFT32 I only get blank rectangular boxes. UTF8 gives me at least alphabet letters.

Comment: What's the content of `ob.Bits`?

Comment: It's a " replacement character" that is shown instead of some invalid unicode characters. So the actual bytes underneath it may be different

Comment: It's extremely unlikely `ob.Bits` is UTF-8. If only you had shown us the actual data instead of a screenshot we would have a chance to guess what encoding it is. You didn't, so we don't.

Comment: What I needed was actually Encoding class `Unicode`... stupidly simple... I added this comment below the answer by Timur below yesterday but I don't see that now. Anyway this was solved!

Comment: @NamelessCosmicDust FYI you *are* allowed to answer your own question, if you managed to solve your issue in a way that may help future readers

Comment: Do not add words like "solved" to the title of questions. If your question has been answered, just accept the answer that best addressed the question.

Comment: I assume that what you actually have is "R\0O\0", which is UTF16, not 8 or 32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
var input = new byte[5];

var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName,
    new EncoderReplacementFallback(""),
    new DecoderReplacementFallback(""));
        
var converted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, encoding, input);

var output = encoding.GetString(converted);
```

This would remove all non-ascii chars with an empty string

Comment: This replaces non-ascii characters, so also letters with accents. So it may work in the particular case of the OP, but maybe not for everyone